# driver isn't navegating to url with list item in it

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Selenium isn't navigating to the url with items of the lists, it gives me an error

this is the part that isn't working in the code:

`driver.get("https://www.dropbox.com/search/work?path=%2F&query=",*list_of_lists[listposition])`

Full code:

```
...
# add list to list
a_file = open("C:/Users/Unknown/Documents/dropbox/find_this.txt", "r")

list_of_lists = []
for line in a_file:
  stripped_line = line.strip()
  line_list = stripped_line.split()
  list_of_lists.append(line_list)

a_file.close()

listtotal = len(list_of_lists)

print("Total:", listtotal)

# create list
links = []

# set position
listposition = 0

while listposition < listtotal:

    driver.get("https://www.dropbox.com/search/work?path=%2F&query=",*list_of_lists[listposition])
    sleep(5)
...
```

this is the list items in the text file "find_this.txt":

```
42508
48157
44179
44597
48156
32250
48160
33343
48162
41628
36063
41983
36064
47438
40941
48165
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`driver.get(url)`**](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html) takes only one parameter.

I see you want to concatenate strings, please do this:

```
while listposition < listtotal:
    driver.get("https://www.dropbox.com/search/work?path=%2F&query=" +list_of_lists[listposition])

...
```

Or using `.format` with add braces `{}`:

```
driver.get("https://www.dropbox.com/search/work?path=%2F&query={}".format(list_of_lists[listposition]))
```

Comment: @FelipeS. welcome, glad to hear, feel free to hit upvote button `^`

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't know i already could vote. i already tried before and i couldn't. but yeh thanks, already upvoted.